# how to get coordinates of primary window

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates

Try to create code, that allow to open or new form like some additional panel with information.
I require that new form open exactly below primary form, so need to find some coordinates of form, but can get only 0 and 0:

code:

```
public int getCoordinateX()
    {
        return this.Location.X;
    }
public int getCoordinateY()
    {
        return this.Location.Y;
    }
```

and on_load next form use

```
private void PlayListForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainForm formObject = new mainForm();
        this.Location = new Point(formObject.getCoordinateX(), formObject.getCoordinateY());
    }
```

where I'm wrong?

Comment: You're creating a whole new mainForm object to get your coordinates, you need to get your coordinates from your existing formMain object.
Pass the old form as a variable into PlayListForm's constructor, or even better just the X/Y coords.

Comment: but how can i send this coordinates from one class to another - think create some methods, that call it in current class, but for calling i require to use `mainForm formObject = new mainForm();` or ther is exist some another way?

Comment: I'll write an answer, one sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're creating a new instance of `mainForm`.

I just used this and it worked.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mainForm form = (mainForm)Application.OpenForms["mainForm"];
        this.Location = new Point(form.GetCoordinateX(), form.GetCoordinateY());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In formMain where you open PlayListForm do:
(this is how you should be opening your new form)

```
        PlayListForm newForm = new PlayListForm(this.Location);
        newForm.Show();
```

Now in form PlayListForm you need to set up it's constructor to recieve this location like so:

```
    public PlayListForm(Point location)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Location = location;
    }
```